# за это написать на js + html

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, сервер, веб-сайт

как написать типа http://домен/и тут &переменная= задать значения

а потом это всё записать
и всё я не могу понять как это сделать просто занимаюсь c# а тут надо написать типо сервера чтобы отправлять туда переменную а потом считывать её

Comment: если говорить о чистом html, изучите тег `<form>` и всё с ним связанное(`<input>, <select>, <textarea>, <button>`, http URL\URI\POST\GET...) это разумеется если говорить о фронте. вам вроде `типо сервера` надо, а это нужно копать в сторону nginx\apache. если нет времени на нормальное изучение или просто лень, можно поставить какой нибудь lamp(open server например). если вам чисто эксперимента ради то и первого попавшегося бесплатного хостинга\VDS\VPS хватит.

Answer (score 0):

Сбор в ссылку

```js
const data = {
  name: "Фогг",
  surname: "Филеас",
  age: 52,
};

const result = Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => encodeURI(`${key}=${value}`)).join(`&`);
console.log(data, result); // В полноценном сайте поставьте код ниже вместе этой строки
// location.search = result;
```

И разбор обратно

```js
const data = `?name=%D0%A4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B3&surname=%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B0%D1%81&age=52`; // В полноценном сайте поставьте код ниже вместе этой строки
// const data = location.search
const result = Object.assign({}, ...data.substring(1).split(`&`).map(variable => {
    const [key, value] = decodeURI(variable).split(`=`);
    return { [key]: value };
}));
console.log(data, result);
```